# Javascript Get div / Insert Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to fetch the div with the id removeNav and paste it back in again. 
but my div is undefined.

```
function init() {
    var insertMenu =  $("#removeNav").html();
    console.log(insertMenu);

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            header = document.querySelector(".navbar-collapse"),
            removeNav = document.getElementById('removeNav'),
            insertNav = document.getElementById('insertNav'),
            body = document.querySelector("body");

            //var insertMenu = '<div id="removeNav" class="navbar-collapse collapse header"><img class="navbar-left" src="img/MRS_Logo_WEB_Interlaced.png" width="120" height="96"> <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> <li class="divider-vertical"></li> <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#about">Login</a></li> <li class="divider-vertical"></li> <li><a href="#contact">Download</a></li> <li class="divider-vertical"></li> <li class="divider-vertical"></li> <li><a href="#about">Karriere</a></li> <li><a href="#contact">Sitemap</a></li> <li class="divider-vertical"></li> <li><a href="#contact">Impressum</a></li> <li class="divider-vertical"></li> <form class="navbar-form navbar-right"> <div class="form-group"> <input class="form-control" placeholder="Suchen" type="text"> </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button> </form> </ul></div>';

        if(distanceY > shrinkOn){
            classie.add(header, "smaller");
            removeNav.parentNode.removeChild(removeNav);
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header, "smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header, "smaller");
                insertNav.innerHTML = insertMenu;
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

My Code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/t23nn1pp/

Comment: Where in the code is your div undefined?

Comment: If it's undefined, it probably means you haven't set it to anything; if it's null, it cannot be found in the DOM.

Comment: In your Fiddle, first, there is no jQuery loaded... Then that is `classie` which is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing jQuery with vanilla JS, change this line:

```
var insertMenu =  $("#removeNav").html();
```

for

```
var insertMenu =  document.querySelector("#removeNav").innerHTML;
```

Snippet below (changed console.log for alert just for demo)

```js
function init() {
  var insertMenu = document.querySelector("#removeNav").innerHTML;
  alert(insertMenu);

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
      shrinkOn = 300,
      header = document.querySelector(".navbar-collapse"),
      removeNav = document.getElementById('removeNav'),
      insertNav = document.getElementById('insertNav'),
      body = document.querySelector("body");

    if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
      classie.add(header, "smaller");
      removeNav.parentNode.removeChild(removeNav);
    } else {
      if (classie.has(header, "smaller")) {
        classie.remove(header, "smaller");
        insertNav.innerHTML = insertMenu;
      }
    }
  });
}
window.onload = init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classie/1.0.1/classie.min.js"></script>

<div id="insertNav">
  <div id="removeNav" class="navbar-collapse collapse header">
    <a href="index.html"><img class="navbar-left img-responsive logo-margin" src="img/MRS_Logo_WEB_Interlaced.png" height="96" width="120" /></a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#about">Login</a></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Download</a></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><a href="#about">Karriere</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Sitemap</a></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Impressum</a></li>
      <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Suchen">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
      </form>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ran your snippet and get the errors "classie is not defined"

Comment: This will work with his setup, thats becuase classie.min.js is not loaded, it's redundant since he is clearly using it and the snippet captures the element he wishes. Anyways, I've added it just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't see they were using classie.min.js as the OP did not mention this.

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t23nn1pp/6/

I know my fix is a little off your original code, however have you tried just hiding and showing the nav bar?

jQuery

```
function init() {
    var $insertMenu = $("#removeNav");

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset;
        var shrinkOn = 100;

        if(distanceY > shrinkOn){
            $insertMenu.hide();
        } else {
            $insertMenu.show();
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

CSS for example

```
body{
  min-height: 2000px;
}

#insertNav{
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  background-color: #F0F;
}
```

Html is the same as you provided.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
Running your code with the link provided, there are a few things missing.
- jQuery
- Classie

As for jQuery, you can try adding:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you fix (or remove, as suggested by others), it'll work.

Comment: jQuery lib is missing... True. But then, even adding it, the code doesn't work. Have you tried scrolling?